# How do I apply formatting like italic or bold to text using ANSI escaping sequences in a console?

Tags: colors, cmd, lua, ascii, ansi-escape

How do I format text with ANSI escaping?

Like make things *italic* or **bold** and maybe strikethrough and super script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable bash output color with Lua script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718403/enable-bash-output-color-with-lua-script)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### How I format like, make things italic or bold using ANSI terminal escape codes?

Bold: Use `ESC[1m`

Italic, Strike-through and Superscript are not supported.

Some terminals support additional sequences. For example in a Gnome Terminal you can use:

> ```
> echo -e "\e[1mbold\e[0m"
> echo -e "\e[3mitalic\e[0m"
> echo -e "\e[4munderline\e[0m"
> echo -e "\e[9mstrikethrough\e[0m"
> echo -e "\e[31mHello World\e[0m"
> echo -e "\x1B[31mHello World\e[0m"
> ```
>
> [image]

Source [How to do: underline, bold, italic, strikethrough, color, background, and size in Gnome Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/a/528938/376050), answer by [Sylvain Pineau](https://askubuntu.com/users/32239/sylvain-pineau)

---

#### Further Reading

- [ANSI Escape sequences](https://web.archive.org/web/20210226122732/http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php)

Comment: is there anyway to use RGB

Comment: @jepjep40 Not with ansi escape sequences.

Comment: @jepjep40 Yes, search for `true 24-bit colors`.

Comment: Actually you can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences/33206814#33206814

Comment: @xeruf You couldn't in 2016 when I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Italic, Strike-through and Superscript are not supported.

Not over here. I wrote the following script and tested it on:

- iTerm2 on macOS (zsh)
- Terminal on macOS (zsh)
- Git Bash on Windows 11
- GNOME Terminal on Ubuntu, Mint (bash)
- Konsole on FreeBSD 13 (bash)

And they all worked, but I didn't see any reference to "superscript" though. What's the esc code for that?

Anyway, I put this script online if anyone wants to try it: [esctest.sh](https://rml.dev/pub/esctest.sh). (don't forget to `chmod +x` first)

PS. You can use `\x1b`, `\033` and `\e` all interchangeably for the ESC.

```
#!/bin/bash

_esc_seq="\x1b["
_esc_end="${_esc_seq}0m"

# $1: escape code
# $2: message
print_test_style() {
    echo -e "\t${_esc_seq}${1}m${2}${_esc_end}\n"
}

declare -a _style_codes=(
    ["1"]="bold"
    ["2"]="dim"
    ["3"]="emphasis"
    ["4"]="underline"
    ["9"]="strikethrough"
)

echo -e "Testing styles...\n"

for key in "${!_style_codes[@]}"; do
    print_test_style "${key}" "${_style_codes[$key]}"
done
```

[image: sample of iTerm2 running this script]